# modifying disk access MacOS 13.3.1

Tags: hard-drive, permission, ventura

it looks like I can just see what apps have disk access (and what level of access they have) rather than modifying it.  How do I actually control access?  I have admin on the machine, but nothing was asked of me in those regards.

I am on MacOS 13.3.1

[image: Screenshot of my System Settings]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can add apps to the list, to give them Full Disk Access, if they need it. Oh, and I recommend not using "cleaner" apps.

Comment: AppCleaner isn't a 'cleaner app', as such, it's an uninstaller; old, solid, tried & tested.